"E: Unable to locate package VirtualBox" Error when I try to install virtualbox in command line
So first off I'm using Ubuntu 22.04LTS
So I was going off this tutorial on how to install virtualbox https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-virtualbox-in-linux/ and it says to go in command line and enter
sudo apt install VirtualBox and thats when I got
sudo apt install VirtualBox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package VirtualBox

So virtualbox is still included in the Ubuntu repository right?

Yes virtualbox is still included in the Ubuntu repository. Here's where things went wrong. Command line is upper and lowercase sensitive. So this is the command I should have entered
sudo apt install virtualbox

And this is what worked for me.
